# How does this template function work? It checks runtime whether type conversion is possible, without using cast

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

```cpp
/// Segédsablon típuskonverzió futás közbeni ellenőrzésere
///That translates into: Helper-template to test type conversion during runtime
template <typename F, typename T>
struct _Is_Types {
    template<typename D> static char (&f(D))[1];
    template<typename D> static char (&f(...))[2];
    static bool const convertable = sizeof(f<T>(F())) == 1;
};
```

This is a code snippet which tests, whether you can cast F to T (or so im told) but i don't really understand it. Please help me

#Edit1:

So i have to expand a skeleton-code, and one of the tests (using gtest_lite) looks like this:

```
TEST(Elkeszult0, sanity_check) {
      if (_Has_String<UString>::member == false)
        FAIL() << "No inheritance" << endl;

      if (_Is_Types<UString, String>::convertable == false)
          FAIL() << "UString can't be converted to String!" << endl;
      if (_Is_Types<String, UString>::convertable == false)
          FAIL() << "String can't be converted to  UString!" << endl;
    } ENDM
```

#Edit2

```
class String
{
  public: 
};


class UString : public String
{
  public: 
};


template <typename F, typename T>
struct _Is_Types {
    template<typename D> static char (&f(D))[1];
    template<typename D> static char (&f(...))[2];
    static bool const convertable = sizeof(f<T>(F())) == 1;
};

/* First instantiated from: insights.cpp:10 */
#ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
template<>
struct _Is_Types<String, UString>
{
  template<typename D>
  static char (&f(D))[1];
  template<typename D>
  static char (&f(, ...))[2];
  
  #ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
  template<>
  static char (&f<UString>(, ...))[2];
  #endif
  
  static const bool convertable = sizeof(f<UString>(String())) == 1;
};

#endif

int main()
{
  _Is_Types<String, UString>::convertable;
  return 0;
}
```

This didn't really help me understand it. So what does the type D explode into? What does it even do, put before a function definition? And what is "f"?

Comment: There is no run-time check that I can see. Can you make a [mre] to make your point?

Comment: It's not runtime, but compiletime.

Comment: Still - why do you think there is a run-time check?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you for your response. I have edited the question with more information

Comment: @TedLyngmo because the prof commented it above the templated struct: "Helper template to test type conversion during runtime"

Comment: And i don't understand why he checks both way. If UString is a subclass of String, how could String be converted into UString?

Comment: @RipplB You can use https://cppinsights.io/ to see instantiations if you are in doubt

Comment: Still, what makes you think there is a run-time check in that instantiation? Where exactly would that be?

Comment: A comment my professor wrote above the struct. He just wrote its runtime.

Comment: I don't see that comment. Perhaps you or your professor made a mistake. What you've shown doesn't lead to any run-time check.

Comment: Well he probably did then. But still, what can I do inside my UString class, so that it passes this testcase? That "_Is_Types<String, UString>::convertable" returns true?

Comment: You _could_ show your professors comment _in context_ .

Comment: Edited it on the top. Also, as i have commented on the answer, i can compile, but test fails on run.

Comment: "_Helper-template to test type conversion during runtime_" is something that should probably have been left at "_type trait_". No - no runtime test is being made.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_Is_Types`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code. (Yes, it looks like your professor did this; it's still wrong!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The check is really done at compile-time.

Let us analyze what each line does.

```
template<typename D> static char (&f(D))[1];
```

This line declares `f` to be a function that takes a parameter of type `D` and returns a reference to a `char[1]`.

```
template<typename D> static char (&f(...))[2];
```

This line overloads `f` as a function that takes any parameter(s) and returns a reference to a `char[2]`.

```
static bool const convertable = sizeof(f<T>(F())) == 1;
```

Finally, the convertibility is evaluated. `f<T>(F())` attempts to call `f<T>` with a parameter of type `F`. If `F` is convertible to `T`, the first overload is chosen and the return type is `char(&)[1]`. Otherwise, the other overload is chosen and return type is `char(&)[2]`. Using the `sizeof` operator, we determine which overload was chosen and we now know whether `F` is convertible to `T`.

Note that this only works if `F` is default-constructible.

Comment: So if String (if we go back to the specific example) does not have a default constructor (which it does'nt, we got it like that) then the test will always fail and I can't really solve the exercise?

Comment: Also, i can compile without warnings or errors, and the test only fails when run

Comment: `String` has no explicit constructor, which means it *is* default-constructible (ie. constructible with no parameters). If it wasn't, your code would not compile at all. Your test fails because `String` really cannot be converted do `UString`. You would have to define a constructor or a conversion operator if you want it to be. Also, I feel obligated to mention that the standard library already has [`std::is_convertible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible)

Comment: Yes i wonder why he didn't use that one... What kind of constructor would me enable that?

Comment: Either a `UString::UString(const String&)` or a `String::operator UString()`. Either will do